# onkeyup function only firing once

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I need the onkeyup to fire more than once, but it seems to be only firing once!

When I enter something into the input box, it searches, but then whenever I backspace and search something else, the div stay's the same..

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function suggest1() {
    var dam_text = document.getElementById('dam').value;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('MicrosoftXMLHTTP');
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    var target = 'dam_search.php?dam_text=' + dam_text;
    xmlhttp.open('GET', target, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<input type="text" name="dam" id="dam" onkeyup="suggest1();"><br />
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Here is dam_search.php

```
<?php

//connect to db stuff here

if (isset($_GET['dam_text'])) {
    $dam = $_GET['dam_text'];
    getSuggest($text);
}

function getSuggest($text) {

    $sqlCommand = "SELECT `name` FROM `table1` WHERE `name` LIKE '%$dam_text%'";

    $query = mysql_query($sqlCommand);

    $result_count = mysql_num_rows($query);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo $row['name'].'<br />';
    }

}
?>
```

ALSO: I am wondering how I can put the return of the name's it has searched into a dropdown from the input box instead of into the div, so when I click on one of the names, it auto fills the input box.

Thank you!

Comment: When you say it only fires once. What exactly do you mean - it only fires once each time a key is released, or it only fires once for the page, or perhaps something else?

Comment: Fires once on each browser load. So, I type "a" and it loads everything with "a" in it, and then when I type a "b", it doesn't fire again. I have to reload the browser for it to reset so it can fire again.

Comment: Hmm, that's more than a little odd. I usually use the AjaxRequest library (http://ajaxtoolbox.com/request/) since it handles multiple parallel requests effortlessly and is much, much lighter than jQuery, which I have no interest in - I'd thought the ajax stuff may have been falling over, but have also cobbled together a functional example from your code. The php is a bit funky - I'm guessing this isn't a copy'n'paste, but rather a look'n'retype problem. I would put the results into an array and then return it as JSON. You can then load and use the elements in the array in any way you please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out my problem. The query wasn't correctly being processed!

I had the variable $dam_text as the LIKE statement, when it should have been $dam:

```
<?php

//connect to db stuff here

if (isset($_GET['dam_text'])) {
    $dam = $_GET['dam_text'];
    getSuggest($text);
}

function getSuggest($text) {

    $sqlCommand = "SELECT `name` FROM `table1` WHERE `name` LIKE '%$dam_text%'";

    $query = mysql_query($sqlCommand);

    $result_count = mysql_num_rows($query);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo $row['name'].'<br />';
    }

}
?>
```

Also, the variable $dam wasn't being submitted inide the function, so I moved it from the 'if' statement, into the function:

```
<?php

//connect to db stuff here

if (isset($_GET['dam_text'])) {
    getSuggest($text);
}

function getSuggest($text) {

    $dam = $_GET['dam_text'];

    $sqlCommand = "SELECT `name` FROM `table1` WHERE `name` LIKE '%$dam%'";

    $query = mysql_query($sqlCommand);

    $result_count = mysql_num_rows($query);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo $row['name'].'<br />';
    }

}
?>
```

The above code works perfectly! Turns out it wasn't onkeyup after all! Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

OnKeyUp will only fire once per event. pressing 'A' 'B' and 'C' will result in three calls to suggest1();

To make sure your browser is working correctly try this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function suggest1() {
     document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = document.getElementById('dam').value;
 }
 </script>
 <input type="text" name="dam" id="dam" onkeyup="suggest1();"><br />
 <div id="myDiv"></div>
```

You should see the div change for every keystroke that occurs in the input.

There is two many unknowns for me to directly point at your actual issue.
Your PHP will output nothing for a zero entry query, and will only output 1 item if you query LIKE only matches one thing. I think your problem lies elsewhere, an not with onkeyup

T test to onkeyup on your system/browser:
Try adding some debug header like `echo strlen($text).'<br />';` to your PHP file. You should see the number change with out relying on your SQL query for every key press that adds or deletes text (that includes the backspace key).

Your code looks fine. And runs fine for me using the public HTTP GET echo service at http://ivanzuzak.info/urlecho/

Swapping out your PHP for the echo service works fine (with a bit of a typing delay)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function suggest1() {
    var dam_text = document.getElementById('dam').value;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('MicrosoftXMLHTTP');
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    var target = 'http://urlecho.appspot.com/echo?body=' + dam_text;
    xmlhttp.open('GET', target, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<input type="text" name="dam" id="dam" onkeyup="suggest1();"><br />
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure about your issue with the keyup only firing once per page-load. That's very hard to speculate reasonably on without seeing more code. Never-the-less, here's an example I just threw together of how you can present the returned data in a more useful way.

The code requires that you download the AjaxRequest library I mentioned in an earlier comment.
(http://ajaxtoolbox.com/request/)

Here, I demo a few principles.

1. Arranging the data into a php class
2. constructing an array of instances of this class
3. returning this array as JSON
4. catching the JSON text and turning it back into an object in JS
5. Processing the data

I've given 2 very simple example - the first simply loads all filenames in the current directory (that holds jsonDir.php) into a select element. Choosing a filename results in it being copied into a text input next to the button.

The second, only retrieves names of png files. It chucks them all into a select element too. This time however, when an item is selected it is used as the src for an image. In each case the filenames are only grabbed if/when the corresponding button is pressed. There's a bit of redundant/otherwise crappy code I could have done better, but after 20 hours awake, I'm ready for bed!

[image: code preview image]

Hope it's useful for you. Any questions, just ask. :)

**1. jsonDir.php**

```
<?php
class mFile
{
    public $name, $time, $size;
}

if (!isset($_GET['wildcard']))
    $wildCard = "*.*";
else
    $wildCard = $_GET['wildcard'];

foreach (glob($wildCard) as $curFilename)
{
    $curFileObj = new mFile;
    $curFileObj->name = $curFilename;
    $curFileObj->time = date("d/m/Y - H:i", filectime($curFilename));
    $curFileObj->size = filesize($curFilename);
    $fileArray[] = $curFileObj;
}
printf("%s", json_encode($fileArray));
?>
```

**2. readDir.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script/ajaxRequestCompressed.js'></script>
<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}

function myGetAjaxResponseWithCallback(url, target, callbackFunc)
{
  AjaxRequest.get(
    {
      'url':url,
      'onSuccess':function(req){ callbackFunc(req.responseText, target); }
    }
  );
}

function getResults1()
{
    var url = "jsonDir.php";
    var target = byId('resultsDiv');
    myGetAjaxResponseWithCallback(url, target, jsonDataReceived1);
}

function getResults2()
{
    var url = "jsonDir.php?wildcard=*.png";
    var target = byId('resultsDiv2');
    myGetAjaxResponseWithCallback(url, target, jsonDataReceived2);
}

function jsonDataReceived1(responseText, targetContainer)
{
    var resultObject = JSON.parse(responseText);
    targetContainer.innerHTML = "";

    var mStr = "There were " + resultObject.length + " records returned" + "<br>";
    var mSel = newEl("select");

    mSel.addEventListener('change', doAutofill, false);

    var i, n = resultObject.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        var curRecordOption = new Option(resultObject[i].name, i);
        mSel.appendChild(curRecordOption);
    }
    targetContainer.innerHTML = mStr;
    targetContainer.appendChild(mSel);
}

function jsonDataReceived2(responseText, targetContainer)
{
    var resultObject = JSON.parse(responseText);
    targetContainer.innerHTML = "";

    var mSel = newEl("select");
    mSel.addEventListener('change', showSelectedImg, false);

    var i, n = resultObject.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        var curRecordOption = new Option(resultObject[i].name, i);
        mSel.appendChild(curRecordOption);
    }
    targetContainer.innerHTML = '';
    targetContainer.appendChild(mSel);
}


function doAutofill(e)
{
    var curSelIndex = this.value;
    var curText = this.options[curSelIndex].label;
    byId('autofillMe').value = curText;
}

function showSelectedImg(e)
{
    byId('previewImg').src = this.options[this.value].label;
}

</script>
<style>
img
{
    border: solid 2px #333;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick='getResults1()'>Get *.* dir listing</button> <input id='autofillMe'/>
    <div id='resultsDiv'></div>
    <hr>
    <button onclick='getResults2()'>Get *.png dir listing</button> <img id='previewImg' width='100' height='100'/>
    <div id='resultsDiv2'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but not exactly what I was looking for! Hopefully this can help someone else!

Comment: No problem. Indeed - I realized it wasn't a solution to your primary question regarding the keyup event.  It should however light the way to the "ALSO" part of your question. It's just a matter of slapping the label of the clicked option into your text input,rather than a second, unrelated one, as I did in the first example. Ahh! Just seen your own solution to the problem. Eccellente!