# cannot manipulate string with javascript - no errors

Tags: javascript, string

I use javascript to manipulate a string.

`data` is a string that came from an XmlHTTP Request (works fine)

The pattern of the data is like this

`id-Name of the folder that file got uploaded-Name Of The File-Type Of The File`

so is like

`34upload/imageTitle.jpgi`

"i" stands for image, for Type of the file. It could also be "v" for video. They always be "i" or "v"

The name of the folder is always `upload/`

So I try to pass those to three different vars.

Like so

```
    //type is always the last char
    var type=data.charAt(data.length-1);

    //folder name+file name+file suffix, so from the first "u" till the last char-1
    var place=data.slice(data.indexOf("u"),data.length-2);

    //the id - from the beggingn to the first "u"
    var splitotgetid=data.split("u");                                           
    var id=splitotgetid[0];
```

Now , only getting the id works fine.

place contains `upload/file.jpgi` - cannot get rid of the last char

and the worst, type, is empty

I see no errors in my console.

I have try many modifications, the problem, is the same...What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: i ran your code here http://jsfiddle.net/p6XL6/ and everything seems to fine in the console, unless i misunderstood you, if you make data.length-1 for both type and place. For input 34upload/imageTitle.jpgi the output is i , upload/imageTitle.jpg and 34. Should it be something else?

Comment: Don't you think it's better to pass a JSON object than a string?

Comment: @melc My point exactly...Everything looks normal. I dont get it. Maybe is something with the `DOM`? Even if it is , why some of the code is wrong, and not all of it?I'll check the code again...

Comment: Have a look at the data variable, by printing it to the console, before manipulation.

Comment: @th1rdey3 You mean, to use `JSON`? I did not get you...

Comment: @melc I alert it, before manipulation and its like `34upload/imageTitle.jpgi` .Looks ok to me

Comment: Yes, instead of sending data as string, send it as JSON from server side.

Comment: See my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337567/onkeyup-function-only-firing-once/19339961#comment28655375_19339961 for an example of returning the filenames as JSON, rather than some mangled string.

Comment: @user2860857 don't use alert, use `console.log`. That way javascript won't try to coerce the data to a string format, and will log it as whatever true format it has.

Comment: @th1rdey3 server side is `php`. I 'll try to use `json_encode` function. I just cannot get why my code does not work, especially when looks fine, and no errors in console...This is so upseting.Anyhow, I'll try `json_encode` and let you know

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks. This is what I get from console. `1348upload/nyeOdigQf4big-bang-theory-cast2.jpgi`looks fine...

Comment: @th1rdey3 Before I use `json` let me ask you something. Checking Chrome's debugger as `response` has this `1353upload/Sc8DYKWR4ubig-bang-theory-penny-front-h/r.jpgi 
↵` What is that last char? I surely did not place it...

Comment: It might be a CR(carriage return) character. Did you place any \n when generating the string?

Comment: @th1rdey3 No...It is just there. SQL or PHP adds it? Anyway, this is standard, so I can do like `var place=data.slice(data.indexOf("u"),data.length-4);` and get the correct sting back. I actually dont know, I never see that chars before. Added by SQL after inserting in a table?